# Change glyphicon with class.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I can change bootstrap glyphicon when I click over my HTML button.

This is my button :

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-choice" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="title">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> {% trans 'Title' %} </button>
```

And this is my JavaScript part :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button-choice').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I don't overcome to click on button and change glyphicon inside.

Comment: Not an answer, but you can write your third line like this: `$(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo (`.button-choice` instead of `.btn-choice`).

Then, you need to find the closest `span` and update it, otherwise the class will be applied to the `button` instead of the inner `span`, and won't work as intended.

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<button class="btn btn-default btn-choice" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="title">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> {% trans 'Title' %} </button>
```

js:

```
$('.btn-choice').click(function () {
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
        //^----------^---- Note this! otherwise it won't work, since it would target $(this), which is the button.
});
```

Your fiddle, updated: https://jsfiddle.net/6ae0c1dL/2/

Comment: Thank you it makes exactly what I want ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be the right way to make it. However, you are listening the click event on the **wrong class** :

```
$(".button-choice")
```

*Instead of*

```
$(".btn-choice")
```

**EDIT :**

You should also **find your span** into your button. One more thing, you can **toggle multiple classes with one** `toggleClass()` call :

```
$(this).find("span").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
```

Comment: You're right, it was a mistake from myself, but look @briosheje answer, with yours, it doesn't work ;)

Comment: Oops. Edited. Also I added a more dry code. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an id to get the span containing the glyphicon. That id being unique in the page, this solution works only for 1 button. A workaround to this can be using some `data-something` to call the correct span.

Plus, you aren't calling the correct class for the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-choice').click(function () {
      let spanId = $(this).data("spanid");
      $('#' + spanId).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button data-spanid="theGlyphicon1" class="btn btn-default btn-choice" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="title">
  <span id="theGlyphicon1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>my button 1
</button>

<button data-spanid="theGlyphicon2" class="btn btn-default btn-choice" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#title" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="title">
  <span id="theGlyphicon2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>my button 2
</button>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using an `id` this approach will work as expected as long as  the button set exists only once in the whole page.

Comment: This was implicit to me, but indeed, it's not necessary implicit for others.

Comment: $(this).find('span') seems to be a better approach than using id.

Comment: I disagree with you @AndréDS For some reasons, there can be many `span` in that button, at any places.

Comment: Then he can combine both of our solutions : $(this).find("span#id") ;)